# Wait file busy another process

Tags: go

I try to create some deamon which look the folde and if we insert new file open this file and do some magic, i use this (https://github.com/howeyc/fsnotify) FS notificator , but if i open file i have error "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process." i find a dirty solution whith time sleep 100 ms , but i think this is not clear way

```
func main(){
watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

done := make(chan bool)

// Process events
go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case ev := <-watcher.Event:
            if ev.IsCreate() == true {
                time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                 file,err := os.OpenFile(path+ev.Name,os.O_RDWR|os.O_EXCL,0755)
                 if err !=nil{
                   panic(err)
                 }
                 //some code
                 file.Close()
            }
        case err := <-watcher.Error:
            log.Println("error:", err)
        }
    }
}()

err = watcher.Watch("test")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

<-done

watcher.Close()
}
```

UPD: Why do I have to do this ? 
I have a task to make the database Webm files , in order to determine if I have already such a file in the database I should get the hash of a file , but in the specification of this format (https://matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html) is the global bit Void block which stores some information , due to the fact that this unit can store different information from the same file will have different hash values , for this I use my function to find this bit block and reset it.

Comment: if i understand the Api correctly   the IsCreated method  notify for the creation of a file only.
 you need to Mack sure that the file inst locked before open it

Comment: I guess the file is still being written while you open it using exclusive r/w, that's why.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini how can i catch moment if file i free ?

Comment: @MIkCode how can i do this ? can u provide some example pls ?

Comment: @which OS  need to run  this code ?

Comment: @MIkCode UNIX/Win

Comment: @izac I do not believe that this is the right approach. You may check if the file is not used, try to open it, and then figure out that it has been opened for exclusive write again - I guess it is part of the nature of concurrent systems. My question is instead, why do you need to tamper with that file? What is the objective you are trying to accomplish? That would help focusing the answer.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini It will be webm files , and to find out that there is no such file in the db I need to reset the last Void element in its structure as because of this element may be a different hash with the same content , it is obvious that 1 time with this file will only work for my demon.

Comment: Can you just edit your question and expand a bit more? Unfortunately English is not my first language and I could not understand what you mean.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini Upd the question

Comment: If you have the control on the part that create the webm file, it could create it under a different folder first and move it afterward. The move (or rename) is instant and the file will not be locked when you will get the notification.

Comment: @mgagnon i create file in another folder and then insert in  watch folder and lib give me create  notification .

Comment: @mgagnon also i try IsModify function and have same error

Comment: @izac have you tried with IsRename?

Comment: @mgagnon if i use CTRL + C file and CTRL + V in folder then event CREATE and x2 MODIFY and file is not lock , if i use drug&drop file in folder event CREATE and lock.